# sftp bash script doesnt downloads files

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

I have a problem with my bash script.

- It connects to my sftp server.
- Gets the list of files to download.
- Should download the files. But it doesnt do this. I can see the commands. if I write the commands manually, it works.

You can see the script and the log files here:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCALDIR="/data/IMPORT/$(date +%Y%m%d)"
REMOTEDIR="/EXPORT"
FILELIST="$LOCALDIR/filelist.txt"
FILELIST2="$LOCALDIR/filelist2.txt"

SFTP="sftp -P 1234 -i /var/xxxxxx.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@xxxxx.xxxx"
PASSPHRASE="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

mkdir -p $LOCALDIR
rm $FILELIST
rm $FILELIST2

allfilenames=()

function readFileList {
expect -c "
spawn $SFTP
expect \"assphrase\"
send \"$PASSPHRASE\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"lcd $LOCALDIR\r\"
send \"ls -l $REMOTEDIR/*\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"exit\r\"
interact " > $FILELIST
}

function getFiles {

myfilenames=("$@")

expect -c "
spawn $SFTP
expect \"assphrase\"
send \"$PASSPHRASE\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"lcd $LOCALDIR\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"cd $REMOTEDIR\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
" >> $FILELIST2

for filepath in "${myfilenames[@]}"
do
file="$(basename -- $filepath)"
expect -c "
send \"get -P $file\r\n\"
sleep 3
expect \"sftp>\"
" >> $FILELIST2
done

expect -c "
send \"exit\r\"
" >> $FILELIST2

}

readFileList

c=0
if [[ -f "$FILELIST" ]]; then
    while read line; do
        filename=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $9 }')
        if [[ "$filename" =~ ^$REMOTEDIR ]] ; then
            allfilenames+=($filename)
        fi
    done < $FILELIST
fi

getFiles "${allfilenames[@]}"
```

filelist.txt looks like:

```
spawn sftp -P 1234 -i /var/xxxxxx.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@xxxxx.xxxx
Enter passphrase for key '/var/xxxxxx.pem':
Connected to xxxxx.xxxx.
sftp> lcd /data/IMPORT/20200401
sftp> ls -l /EXPORT/*
-rw-r--r--    0 1000472  1000472      3681 Mar 31 22:31 /EXPORT/file1.txt
-rw-r--r--    0 1000472  1000472     14537 Mar 31 22:34 /EXPORT/file2.txt
-rw-r--r--    0 1000472  1000472      5932 Mar 31 22:34 /EXPORT/file3.txt
sftp> exit
```

filelist2.txt looks like:

```
spawn sftp -P 1234 -i /var/xxxxxx.pem -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@xxxxx.xxxx
Enter passphrase for key '/var/xxxxxx.pem':
Connected to xxxxx.xxxx.
sftp> lcd /data/IMPORT/20200401
sftp> cd /EXPORT
sftp> get -P file1.txt
get -P file2.txt
get -P file3.txt
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expect -c 'spawn sftp ...'

expect -c 'send "get file\r" '
```

Here when the first `expect -c` completes, the SFTP connection will be closed so the second `expect -c` would not work. You have to use one single `expect -c` for one SFTP session.

It's like when you manually sftp to the server, you cannot temporarily go back to Bash and come back to sftp later.

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). it can spawn sftp in background, then you can run any shell commands, and then you can continue talking to the sftp session. that's to say you can freely switch between the sftp session and shell at any time.